# Landsat 8 - NDVI Global Servises - Clouds

Tags: wms, web-service, ndvi, landsat-8

I'm looking for Landsat 8 NDVI Global Services, like [ArcGIS Online](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a1c373b16db34ef687ddae7c482e0b27), but including scenes with the high presence of clouds (50-95%). Fresh scenes with clouds needed because they can contain the areas of interest without clouds.

Comment: Why would you want to calculate the NDVI of a cloud?

Comment: Have you considered using the [Landsat CDR (surface reflectance) product](http://landsat.usgs.gov/CDR_LSR.php) or alternatively employing fmask for cloud masking and calculating the NDVI yourself?

Comment: Fresh scenes with clouds needed because they can include the areas of interest without clouds.

Comment: If there is a service from the cloud images - much more convenient to use an existing service, rather than create its own.